# Open vs Consult in SWI Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog, please just don't blast me.

Whenever i had to consult a prolog database i used the predicate consult/1 :

```
consult(:File)
```

Now, i noticed that there exist also the predicate open

```
open(+SrcDest, +Mode, --Stream, +Options)
```

that allows to read a database.
Apart the possibility to modify the database, not allowed by consult, which are the differences between consult and open (maybe in the extensions of the files that each predicate can open, or maybe because consult reads fact and rules, while with open we can read terms) ?

Comment: Note that facts and rules (and directives) **are** terms.

Comment: `consult` asserts the contents of the file. `open` does not.

Comment: However, why facts and rules are also used as predicates ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. And it's different than what you're asking in your post. A predicate in Prolog is a set of facts and rules with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

Using `consult/1` seems to be quite similar to use `?- [filename]`. Using `consult/1` in your program, you can have access to all the facts and predicates written into the file. So for instance if you have a file `data.pl` like this:

```
fact(a).
fact(b).
fact(c).

hello:-
    writeln('hello').
```

You can create a file, `test.pl` and use all the facts and predicate of `data.pl`:

```
run:-
    consult(prova),
    findall(A,fact(A),L),
    hello,
    writeln(L).

?- run.
hello
[a,b,c]
true.
```

Moreover, consult seems to accept only `.pl` file with a dictionary sructure. On the other hand, with `open/3`, you can access each type of file and read also char by char, but you cannot access the predicates and facts written into the file:

```
run:-
    open('prova.pl',read,Str),
    findall(A,fact(A),L),
    hello,
    writeln(L).

?- run.
ERROR: Undefined procedure: fact/1
```

Obviously, with `open/3` or `open/4` you can create, write into files and so on.

Comment: @Koinos Prolog doesn't care what file extension you use as long as you specify it. The `.pl` extension is the normal convenient for a Prolog source file, and you can consult `foo.pl` with simply, `[foo]`. But if you have `foo.dat` you can consult with `['foo.dat']`.